# Calculate a reward on each sale

Tags: php, laravel

I offer a catalog of several products with different prices. I want to reward the sponsors with a percentage (e.g. 10%) on each sale they generate. The sponsor_id column can be empty if the sale has not been concluded by a sponsor.

EDIT 1: The user_id and sponsor_id columns are foreign keys that point to the User model.

**I would like to know the amount of reward for each sponsor based on the sales they have enabled.**

**Sales table**

| id | user_id | product_id | sponsor_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 31 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 |  |

In the example above, user 30 has allowed two sales (product 1 and 2) and user 31 has allowed one sale (product 1). Sale 4 does not have a sponsor.

```php
$sales = Sale::whereNotNull('sponsor_id')
->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
->get();

foreach($sales as $key => $sale)
{
    //some calculations
}
```

Comment: This question is helpful for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632915/advanced-wherenotnull-statement-in-laravel

Comment: This question is helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632915/advanced-wherenotnull-statement-in-laravel

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

*Sales table :*

| id | user_id | product_id | sponsor_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 31 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |  |

*Users table :*

| id | sponsor_title |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | **** |
| 31 | **** |

Model : (Relationship: User with Sale)

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function salesList()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sale::class, 'sponsor_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function userList()
    {
        $users = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->get();

        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            $salesList = $user->salesList(); // returns total sales collection object by user.
            print_r($salesList); 
            // by looping $salesList variable you can assign sales reward to perticular user.
        }
    }
}
```

If the user is the sponsor in the sales then, it should be the same relationship with sales to the user and you can loop the user's object and get sales generated by the user (sponsor).

I hope you could understand.

Comment: A sponsor is also a user, any buyer can become a sponsor.